# CS0116 A name Space Cannot Directly Contain Members Such As Fields Or Methods

Tags: c#, 2d

I don't know why the script I'm using won't work and I've tried a lot of times to get it to work, but it just doesn't. I've looked around on vids, sites and just everywhere but I can't find a solution. So now I hope I've come to the right place, but anyways here's the script and the error I'm getting.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D
{

    [RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platf    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
        private bool jump;

        public object CrossPlatformInputManager { get; private set; }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character
        {
            get
            {
                return Character2;
            }

            set
            {
                Character2 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump2;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump2 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character1
        {
            get
            {
                return Character2;
            }

            set
            {
                Character2 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump1
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump2;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump2 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character2
        {
            get
            {
                return Character3;
            }

            set
            {
                Character3 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump2
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump3;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump3 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character3
        {
            get
            {
                return character;
            }

            set
            {
                character = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump3
        {
            get
            {
                return jump;
            }

            set
            {
                jump = value;
            }
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            Character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!Jump)
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
            Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Read the inputs.
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
            Character.Move(h, crouch, Jump);
            Jump = false;
        }
    }
}Platformer2DUserControl.cs : MonoBehaviour
```

And The Problem(s) im getting is 'CS0116 A name Space Cannot Directly Contain Members Such As Fields Or Methods' , and that 'Platformer2DUserControl.cs doesnt exist in the current context'

If you have a solution or a tip pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class definition to:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
public class Platf : MonoBehavior
{
    // Implementation
} // remove: Platformer2DUserControl.cs : MonoBehaviour
```

The part after the closing bracket was interpreted as something you wanted to declare. To define inheritance, you just add `:` after the class name, followed by the name of the class you want to inherit from.

**EDIT**
In the end your code would look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D
{

    [RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platf : MonoBehavior    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
        private bool jump;

        public object CrossPlatformInputManager { get; private set; }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character
        {
            get
            {
                return Character2;
            }

            set
            {
                Character2 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump2;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump2 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character1
        {
            get
            {
                return Character2;
            }

            set
            {
                Character2 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump1
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump2;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump2 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character2
        {
            get
            {
                return Character3;
            }

            set
            {
                Character3 = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump2
        {
            get
            {
                return Jump3;
            }

            set
            {
                Jump3 = value;
            }
        }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character3
        {
            get
            {
                return character;
            }

            set
            {
                character = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Jump3
        {
            get
            {
                return jump;
            }

            set
            {
                jump = value;
            }
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            Character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!Jump)
                // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
            Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Read the inputs.
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
            Character.Move(h, crouch, Jump);
            Jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont relly understand, should i copuy that and replace '[RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platf    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
        private bool jump;

        public object CrossPlatformInputManager { get; private set; }

        public PlatformerCharacter2D Character
        {' or should i just put it in the end or something can you explain a bit more clearly so its easier for me to understand?